# CS50P problems Set 5

Tags: python, cs50

in CS50P Problem 5 call "Re-requesting a Vanity Plate"(https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/5/test_plates/)
This program works but I am confused about it
why i have did write "return valid" and "return invalid" two times for each
what's the diffrent?

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    print(is_valid(plate))

def is_valid(s):
    if 2 <= len(s) <= 6 and s[0:2].isalpha() and s[0] != 0 and s.isalnum():
        for char in s:
            if char.isdigit():
                index = s.index(char)
                if s[index:].isdigit() and char != 0:
                    return "Valid"
                else:
                    return "Invalid"
        return "Valid"
    return "Invalid"





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i except to write "return "Valid"" and "return "Invalid"" one time

Comment: The problem statement is that the function should return True or False. Also, s[0] != 0 makes no sense as s[0] will be a character so it will never be equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you shouldn't return values at different points in a function. It's often possible to have single returns of True/False but that will invariably involve lots of if/and/or constructs that make the code difficult to maintain and understand.

Better to break down the logic into its discrete components.

e.g.,

```
def is_valid(plate):
    if not 2 <= len(plate) <= 6:
        return False
    if not plate[:2].isalpha():
        return False
    if not plate.isalnum():
        return False
    for i, c in enumerate(plate[2:], 2):
        if c.isdecimal():
            if c == "0":
                return False
            if not plate[i:].isdecimal():
                return False
            break
    return True
```

Note the use of isdecimal rather than isdigit. The former tests strictly for values in the range 0-9 whereas the latter would also return True for superscript digits which would (obviously) not be valid on a licence plate

Comment: @nocomment depends which country you're in

Comment: Hmm, and there is no country where superscript digits are valid? I at least disagree that that's "obvious".